# Android background process with UI interaction

Tags: android, user-interface, service, process, background

I'm struggling now for some days with a background process i want to include. I have read a lot about it, came across Handlers, Loopers, Services, IntentServices... All that stuff. But i still don't have an idea how to implement any of these.

The background process should be periodically executed and ask a server, some json-request stuff. After that, there should be a toast/notification, something like that. at least an UI action.

Any hints?

Comment: use a Service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Okay, that put some clarity into my thoughts. thanks for that, mate